# Navigating from one viewController to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation

I have a problem in my app related to navigation.My app consists of an initial configurationVC, then loginVC and after logging in the landingVC. After logging in if anywhere in the app, the user encounters a condition like 'invalid id' i need to take him back to the configuration controller.Everywhere i have handled this by keeping a common navigation controller which begins from configurationVC and then using the popToRootViewController on encountering 'invalid id'. But on landingVC i open a leaveVC in a different navigation cntroller.I am doing this as I need to present LeaveVC modally in formSheet style on landing page. So if i do popToRootViewController i wont directly navigate to configurationVC. What should I do to directly get the configurartion screen in this case. 
I have searched a few links but wasnt able to get an adzact solution. Kindly help, as I am a newbie to iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can have ConfigurationVC and loginVC as seperate navigationControllers.
When ever you want ConfigurationVC change the application window rootViewController to ConfigurationVC.

Comment: Even if i have a separate configuration VC and login VC as my navigation controller, still, wouldn't the problem persist? Since i am having a separate navigation controller for my LeaveVC.If i am misunderstanding ur logic please correct me. Are u asking me to set the root view controller to configuration controller once i encounter 'invalid id'? @Mohan

Comment: @user3359535 Yes. Write two methods in AppDelegate. one for setting the rootViewController to ConfigurationVC and another for loginVC. so that you can call those when ever you want.

Comment: @user3359535 if you want you can post notifications instead of calling methods... Those notifications can be implemented in AppDelegate

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via local notification. On LoginVC, you can register for local notification. While you are dismissing leaveVC, you can post the notification from its completion handler. This will invoke a function written in LoginVC, where you are having access of common navigation controller. Using that common navigation controller, you can drop the entire hierarchy.

In LoginVC, in viewDidLoad, write following code,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(removeHierarchy)
                                             name:@"RemoveHierachy"
                                           object:nil];
```

In LoginVC, in dealloc method write following code,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self;
```

In LeaveVC, where you are dismisong the controller (probably in completion handler),

```
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RemoveHierachy" object:nil];
```

Comment: How would i achieve it via a local notification? can you help me with the code?I havent yet used any notifications in my app and dont know how to go about it.@Apurv